# React Three Fiber and Three.js doesn't play animation correctly in React

Tags: reactjs, next.js, three.js, react-three-fiber, gltf

I load GLTF model downloaded from Sketchfab (https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/a-windy-day-fb78f4cc938144e6902dd5cff354d525) in React app. Model loads perfectly well, but animation doesn`t play at all. I tried different approaches, but the animation just blurs over and starts for the beginning like. Any ideas?

```
import React, { Suspense, useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Canvas, useFrame, useLoader } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { OrbitControls, Preload, useGLTF, useAnimations } from "@react-three/drei";
import * as THREE from "three";
import { 
  GLTFLoader 
} from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader';
import CanvasLoader from "../Loader";

const Earth = (props) => {
  const group = useRef();
  const model = useLoader(
    GLTFLoader,
    "./a_windy_day/scene.gltf"
)

  // Here's the animation part
    // ************************* 
    let mixer;
    if (model.animations.length) {
        mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(model.scene);
        model.animations.forEach(clip => {
            const action = mixer.clipAction(clip)
            action.play();
        });
    }

    useFrame((state, delta) => {
        mixer?.update(delta)
    })
    // *************************

    model.scene.traverse(child => {
        if (child.isMesh) {
            child.castShadow = false
            child.receiveShadow = false
            child.material.side = THREE.FrontSide
        }
    })

    return (
      <primitive 
          object={model.scene}
          scale={props.scale}
      />
  )
}

const EarthCanvas = () => {
  return (
    <Canvas>
      <Suspense fallback={null}>
        <Earth />
      </Suspense>
    </Canvas>
  );
};

export default EarthCanvas;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to animate this 3D model - https://skfb.ly/oJMqo with a similar codepen. Yours should work too. Download the GLB model instead of GLTF tho.

```
import { Suspense, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Canvas, useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { OrbitControls, Preload, useGLTF } from "@react-three/drei";
import * as THREE from "three";
import CanvasLoader from "@/components/Canvas/Loader.jsx";

const Crystal = (props) => {
  const [mixer] = useState(() => new THREE.AnimationMixer());

  const group = useRef();
  const actions = useRef();
  const model = useGLTF("./3DModels/crystal/crystal.glb");
  const { nodes, scene, materials, animations } = model;

  useFrame((state, delta) => mixer.update(delta));
  useEffect(() => {
    actions.current = { idle: mixer.clipAction(animations[0], group.current) };
    actions.current.idle.play();
    return () => animations.forEach((clip) => mixer.uncacheClip(clip));
  }, []);

  return (
    <group ref={group} dispose={null}>
      <primitive
        ref={group}
        object={nodes["RootNode"]}
        scale={0.01}
        position-y={0}
        rotation-y={0}
        {...props}
      />
    </group>
  );
};

const CrystalCanvas = () => {
  return (
    <Canvas
      shadows
      frameloop={"always"}
      dpr={[1, 2]}
      gl={{ preserveDrawingBuffer: true }}
      camera={{
        fov: 80,
        near: 0.1,
        far: 200,
        // position: [-4, 3, 1] //just something I was trying, remove it.
      }}
    >
      <Suspense fallback={<CanvasLoader />}>
        <OrbitControls
          // autoRotate //For auto rotation
          enableZoom={false}
          enablePan={false}
          //For locking vertical movement of the object.
          // maxPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
          // minPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
        />
        <Crystal />
        <Preload all />
      </Suspense>
    </Canvas>
  );
};

export default CrystalCanvas;
```